# SQL Full Text Search Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, full-text-catalog

i am trying to implement a full text search on a login table and when i am executing the respective query then following are my observations:

When i am executing the following query implementing the full text search it is able to fetch approximate **1665 rows**

```
select * from t_user where contains(LOGIN_ID, '"*david*" )
```

but when implementing the similar query without using full text search using the following it is returning **1872 rows**

```
select * from T_USER where LOGIN_ID like '%david%'
```

As i browsed throw the data in my table i came to a conclusion that when i am using the contains keyword it is neglecting the row which has login id like **DDAVID_D** or i may say it is only returning rows which have the david words separated like **DAVID_FRANK**.

Is there a way to search a word between the words **(like searching for David in between DDavidFrank or i may searching between long continous words for the david string like in DDAVIDFRANK )** as to implement full text search effectively ?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
WHERE FREETEXT(LOGIN_ID, 'david') OR CONTAINS(LOGIN_ID, 'david')"
```

Comment: tried it, its also fetching 1665 rows and ignoring rest... :(

Comment: i hope the full-text search does not try to use case-sensitive search or sql server collation applied to your database messing your full-text search. is it Latin1_General_CI_AS?

Comment: well earlier had tried on Latin1_General_CI_AS then changed to SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS still same issues...

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
SELECT * from t_user WHERE CONTAINS(LOGIN_ID, '"david"' )
```